# What is the probability of a given permutation if I have individual probabilities of each item in reference to another?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 4 results represented by A, B, C and D

I have the probabilities for whether each result will be greater than the other:

P(A>B): 86.6%

P(A>C): 80.4%

P(A>D): 72.6%

P(B>C): 57.4%

P(B>D): 41.2%

P(C>D): 37.7%

I also assume they can't be the same result.

How do I determine the probability that the results will be in a certain order?
P(A>B>C>D)

I am interested in a formula and theory, as I will need to repeat this for other iterations and scale this to larger sets (i.e. A to J)

Comment: You cannot.  There are 24 possible orderings.  Their chances have to sum to $1$.  You have listed six definite facts about sums of those chances.  That leaves *at least* $24-6-1=17$ degrees of freedom to determine the answer.  Apart from rare exceptional cases, there will not be a unique solution; there's a wide range of solutions.

Comment: Thank you. What other facts would be necessary? I may have access to more probabilities, I just gave what I thought was relevant.

Comment: You will need at least $23$ distinct probabilities.  The 24th can be deduced from the fact they all sum to $1$. This is easier to see in the case of three results. Ignoring $D$ in your question gives a nice example. Writing "$ABC$" for the chance that $A\gt B\gt C$, *etc*, one solution is $(ABC,ACB,BCA,BAC,CAB,CBA)=(0.44,0.364,0.134,0,0.062,0)$ and another solution is $(0.44,0.23,0,0.134,0.196,0)$, as you can check. (These are as extreme as $ACB$ can be: that's how I chose them.)